# How do I read data from a USB connected Scale and send it to a website?

Tags: web, usb, interfacing

So I am trying to pull a weight from a physical scale connected via USB. What I want is to click on a button on my website once an item is placed on the scale and have it read the weight and input it in a field. Shipstation.com has this functionality. They have the user install some software on their computer (shiptstation connect) that then interfaces with the scale and relays the data to their site. The scale itself does not include any software with it. Any ideas on how/where to start working on something like this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this using Node JS and HID library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).